# How to add only online members telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

Please I need help! I've tried everything

how can i add only members online on telegram? which function to use? how to use userupdate?

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate)
async def handler(event):
if event.online:
    print("online")
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code which we could simply copy and try to modify it .

Comment: Remember mass adding members is considered spam and will get both the group and account deleted.

Comment: Okaay i'm going to do that